# How to convert a negative decimal number to binary using linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wanted to convert a negative number to binary using 2's complement but i can't put a proper logic for it. How to convert a negative decimal number to binary using linked list?

A friend of mine is saying that it is a problem of signed bits or something like that

I am at a beginner and cannot find solution for this. I have searched all the web but found nothing.

```
struct node {
    long data;
    node* next;
}* head,* tail;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    long dec;
    cout << "Enter the decimal number" << endl;
    cin >> dec;
    div(dec);
    dis();
    singlecomp();
    dis();
    return 0;
}
void div(long num) {
    while (num != 0) {
        createNode(num % 2);
        num /= 2;
    }
}
void createNode(long val) {
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail = temp;

    } else {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void dis() {
    node* cur = new node;
    cur = head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        cout << cur->data << " ";
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
void singlecomp() {
    node* now = new node;
    now = head;
    cout << endl;
    while (now != NULL) {
        if (now->data == 0) {
            now->data = 1;
        } else {
            now->data = 0;
        }
        now = now->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: The decimal to binary conversion is already done at `cin >> dec`. What you're doing thereafter is isolating the binary digits, which already exist.

Comment: @JamesZ Edit rejected. Your version would not even compile.

Comment: Your friend is misinformed, or you have misunderstood. There is no such thing as a 'signed bit'.

Comment: @user207421 My version was just fixing your code layout. There are no other than whitespace changes, and it was an automated code formatting.

Comment: @JamesZ Your version introduced the non-existent operator `- >`. \

Comment: @user207421 Oh, now I see it. Shouldn't use whatever random pages for formatting code :D

Comment: Are you aware of how a negative number is represented in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)? Are you specifically requested to use a *list* of bits (`long` in your implementation...)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting from C++11, the division for negative values is specified as truncating toward zero. Before that, the direction of rounding was implementation-defined and your code could theoretically result in an infinite loop on some platforms.
2. For the currently acting standards, C++ allows for 3 representations of negative numbers:

   - Signed magnitude
   - One's complement
   - Two’s complement

Your code implements one's complement, while the vast majority of the computing platforms (practically all I know) use two's complement.

3. C++ long type is typically 32- or 64-bit. You need to add enough leading ones to your complemented value to fill the bits your current algorithm doesn't fill, because it stops at reaching value 0 and not at enumerating all 32 or 64 bits.
4. The easiest way of producing a binary representation of a signed long on a given platform is by converting it to an unsigned long first, and then using division/remainder (or shift/bitwise-and) on an unsigned value.

Comment: Hmmm actually i didn't knew this. Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion worked like a charm.